# Can you convert from a less granular to a more granular time type using tick/java.time?

Tags: clojure, java-time

I'm wondering if there is a way to convert from a less granular to more granular time type using `tick` (or java.time upon which tick is based)?

This doesn't work:

```
(-> (t/date "2015") (t/date))
;; => No implementation of method: :date of protocol: #'tick.core/IExtraction found
;; => for class: java.time.Year
```

It makes sense to me that it might not be possible to convert in this direction given that you are basically adding data, and so you'd have to make assumptions, for example picking the month and day to move to pick a date. Given that, you can "cast" from more to less granularity:

```
(-> (t/date "2015-01-01") (t/year))
;; => #time/year "2015"
```

The only way I can think to do this is to convert via strings:

```
(->> (t/year "2015")
     (t/format (t/formatter "yyyy"))
     (#(str % "-01-01"))
     (t/date))
;; => #time/date "2015-01-01"
```

But this feels a bit hack-ey. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
(require '[clojure.instant :as ci])
(ci/read-instant-timestamp "2015")
=> #inst"2015-01-01T00:00:00.000000000-00:00"
```

or

```
(t/zoned-date-time 2015)
```

Comment: Hmmm your first example is not super helpful to me as it just uses a library @akond. The second is interesting, except it appears not to work. When I try to use tick's `zoned-date-time` in that way I get an error, e.g. `(t/zoned-date-time "2015") ;; => could not be parsed at index 4`.

Comment: "2005" is a string, not an integer. `java-time` is not a library?

Comment: :I tried treating `2015` as a string, i.e. `(t/zoned-date-time)`, but it errored. Re: `clojure.instant`, so that require line is importing a wrapper of the java.time class `java.time.Instant`? I see. I'll try that. If both of these approaches do in fact work, I wonder what the differences is. I guess in one case you get an instant and the other a ZonedDateTime, so I suppose a ZonedDateTime has more information (e.g. time zone)...?